# Change default sharing of newly created google spreadsheet

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, gspread

Is there any option or setting to set the default sharing of newly created google spreadsheet, in order that a service account can read them using gspread api? I don’t want to share manually every new spreadsheet.

Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal as follows.

- From `Is there any option or setting to set the default sharing of newly created google spreadsheet, in order that a service account can read them using gspread api?`,

  - You want to create the permission for writing using the service account to new Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using gspread.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Spreadsheet using Sheets API and also, you can use Drive API.

In this case, I thought that the method of `insert_permission` of gspread might be able to be used. When this is used for the Spreadsheet, it becomes as follows. `insert_permission` uses Drive API.

#### Sample script:

```
client = gspread.authorize(credentials) # Please use your "credentials" here.

newSpreadsheetTitle = 'sample' # Please set the new Spreadsheet title.
emailAddress = '###' # Please set the email address of the service account.
folderId = '###' # If you want to create new Spreadsheet to the specific folder. Please use this.

spreadsheetId = client.create(newSpreadsheetTitle, folder_id=folderId).id
client.insert_permission(spreadsheetId, emailAddress, 'user', 'writer')
```

- When above script is run, a new Spreadsheet is created and a permission is created to the created Spreadsheet.

#### Reference:

- [insert_permission](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=permission#gspread.Client.insert_permission)